# Cannot publish a canceled event using Eventbrite API method event_update

Tags: eventbrite

everyone.

I am working with eventbrite's API for my application and am trying to update an eventbrite event using the method event_update. The call worked when I tried to cancel a live event but it doesn't work when I try to re-publish a canceled event. I can publish a canceled event from the "Quick Links" provided for each event under my account's "My Events" tab. So, I was wondering if this can be done using the API as well. The documentation for event_update says that allowed values for status field are “draft”, “live”, “canceled”, “deleted” but when I do the update, I get the following error:

Event deleted or cancelled.

Any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, a canceled event can only be made live again through the Quick Links in the My Events tab of your account. It's not possible to make a canceled event live through the Manage page or the API. This information has been passed along to the API team, and this should be resolved in the coming weeks. We'll let you know once it's been updated!